# Python, open a file when the name is not fully known

Tags: python, file

I have a list of files with names such as these:

`20140911_085234.csv`
`20140912_040056.csv`

What is known is the first part which is the date (the second is a random number). How can I open the correct file if I know the date?

Update: There is one file per day.

Comment: list the directory with `os.listdir`, match the filename with `fnmatch.fnmatch` and then open the file.

Comment: Use the glob package to find the files that you want. It would look like this: files = glob.glob('20140811*'). That will select all the files that start with that date.

Comment: do you only have one file per date ? What is the role of the random number ? If you can manually look at the directory and identify which file is correct, then you should be able to use a combination of the glob module or os.listdir to identify the file. If there are multiple files per day, then you might struggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @isedev says, you could use the fnmatch method to find all the files with the "date" pattern. The code could be like this:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch
import os

folder_path = '/home/Desktop/project'
all_files = os.listdir(folder_path)
content_file = 'Hello World'
_date = '20140911'
_pattern = _date + '*'
for file_name in all_files:
    if fnmatch(file_name, _pattern):
        with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), 'wb') as f:
           f.write(content_file)
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: This assumes that there is only one file per day - doesn't it. I don't think that the OP was explicit that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `glob` :

```
import time
import glob
import os

def open_file_by_date(date):
    path = "/path/to/file"
    files = glob.glob1(path, date + "_*.csv")
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'wb') as f:
           #do your stuff with file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") 
    open_file_by_date(today)
```